# How to detect turtle objects intersecting in python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm using turtle and inserting 2 shapes into the program and I am trying to make the program perform a specific function when the objects intersect. Is it possible to do it with an if statement?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the proper answer is "no".  Turtle graphics does not maintain the shape in a form useful for you to test, nor does it provide shape manipulation methods.

You *could* develop your own package to represent objects, and include an intersection method, but this takes a lot of work.  If you're interested, see the BOOST library shape methods (that's in C++) that Luke Simonson did (2009, I think).

However, if your shapes are regular enough, you *can* make a proximity detector.  For instance, if the shapes are more or less circular, you could simply see whether they've come within r1 + r2 of each other (a simple distance function on their current positions), where r1 & r2 are the radii of the objects.  Is that close enough for your purposes?